# Saving TIFF file as PNG with colour ramp

Tags: python, raster, png

I have one TIFF image having the pixel value of 1 and 2. It's a classified image. I want to save the TIFF file as a PNG with heading and colour index for 1 and 2. I can able to plot the raster but issue with indexing, giving colour.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: If you're going to have a raster with two values, they should be 0 and 1, not 1 and 2 (1-bit is a quarter the size of 4-bit). A "color ramp" on two value classification is a *non sequitur*.

Comment: @Vince I think the OP wants to assign colours (pseudocolours in RGB/CMYK/HSV) to the values of 1 and 2 not so much a ramp. Perhaps the values are 1 and 2 so that 0 can be NoData.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the library you are using to manipulate your images. However, this can be done reasonably easily using [pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/).

```py
from PIL import Image

img_path = r"path\to\image.tif"

# open the image and convert to 3-channel RGB
img = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')

# get the image data
data = img.getdata()

new_pixel_values = []
for pixel in data:
    # find pixels with value 1
    if pixel == (1, 1, 1):
        # replace with a specified colour
        new_pixel_values.append((115, 137, 174))
    
    # you can use `elif` here to specify other values
    # elif pixel == (2, 2, 2):
        # new_pixel_values.append((255, 212, 0))

    # or just catch the remainder with `else`
    else:
        # specify colour for remaining pixels
        new_pixel_values.append((244, 51, 171))

# update the pixel values
img.putdata(new_pixel_values)

# save the RGB image
outpath = img_path[:-4] + '_rgb.png'
img.save(outpath)
```

[image]